# spark-memory fraction and executor memory overhead?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> what is "spark.executor.memoryOverhead" and "spark.memory.fraction"?
>
> what is the default properties

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why increase spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988475/why-increase-spark-yarn-executor-memoryoverhead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spark.memory.fraction` parameter can be used to separately understand memory available for storage and memory available for execution. If you are caching too many objects in memory then you will need more of storage (`spark.memory.fraction` can be 0.5/0.6). However, if you are using memory for largely execution purposes then you need memory to be available for execution (`spark.memory.fraction` can be 0.2/0.3).